# Searching for values in JSON array w/ stdClass subarray

Tags: php, arrays, json, woocommerce, stdclass

This JSON snippet is part of a WooCommerce order, extracted from the APIv2 get_order() function. The [meta] holds product variation data chosen by the customer.

`[meta] => Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [key] => pa_size [label] => Size [value] => Large ) 
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [key] => pa_color [label] => Choose Color [value] => Black )`

How do I search the stdClass object for a particular [key] and return its corresponding [value]?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can you explain in detial

Comment: @Prakash it was a pretty badly worded question. I think what I meant to ask was, "How do I search the stdClass object for a particular [key] and return its corresponding [value]?"

Comment: Please try my code, It should work as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   $meta = array();   //Suppose that your array is $meta

   $your_key="pa_size"; // if you are trying to search for "pa_size"
   $your_value=""; // will retrun value "Large"

   foreach( $meta as $obj )
   {
        if( $obj->key == $your_key )
        {
            $your_value = $obj->value;
            break;
        }
   }

   echo $your_value; // will retrun value "Large"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
foreach ($rows as $object) {
{
    $size  = $object->pa_size;
    $color = $object->pa_color;
    // more code
}
```